# Run Script every day in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

I'm not sure if this capability exists but I thought it'd be worth asking. I just started working at a company that uses outlook and I'm trying to set up a feature that I've been using in my gmail for quite some time.

Basically I want to be able to send my emails into some sort of 'view tomorrow' folder which will hide the email and then in the next day bring it back to my inbox.

In gmail I set up a script to run around 1am everyday that would move everything from the 'view tomorrow' folder to my inbox and would handle this feature (in fact I've set it up for up to 7 days).

Does outlook have a way of running rules every day at a certain time or something else of the sort that could help me create this functionality?

Any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen/tried [Delay or schedule sending email messages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-253dbfd7-0db7-4f41-bcc5-9e8e68ae29bf) yet?

Comment: Thanks for looking at my post @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007. Unfortunately I'm looking to 'delay' inbound not outbound messages

Comment: Ahhh gotcha!  OK, one more suggestion to check into would be the [Follow-up flags](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Track-e-mail-messages-that-require-follow-up-9D0F175F-F3E9-406D-BBF7-9C57E1F781CC#bm7).  Not an exact analog, but it may lead you to something more like what you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks! I've been playing with those, but I miss the benefit of having it completely out of sight...

Answer (score 0):

You can create this functionality using Outlook built-in features. In order to achieve the desired result do the following:

1. Create Outlook rule(s) that will move messages to required folder(s) as needed. Do not enable these rules, just leave them turned off!
2. Create recurring Outlook task or calendar event with reminder that will fire at the specific time. As alternative,
3. Create Application_Reminder hevent handler that will will fire your turned off rules for required folders.